# How to implement a destroyable wall in iPhone game development

Tags: iphone

I'm pretty routined in writing iPhone applications with common UIViews.
To extend my skills, I wanted to write a simple 2D game where a player needs to break complex wall structure with limited shoots.

One shot should demage the wall, but not break through. A second shot at the same position would break through the wall.

No I ask myself how to handle such thing. I think drawing a shape wouldn't do the job since the wall should look damaged at the hit point.

I could draw the wall be setting single pixles. Then I could erase every set pixel in the impact area. But I think this would be very slow and memory consuming.

How to manage such things ?

Comment: I think you should edit the question to remove iPhone, as it looks you already know how to do iPhone dev, its more the approach at a higher-level? I have no answer (in any language or API) as I focus on business apps but it goes to show how little I (maybe we) know about game dev.

Comment: Seems like iPhone is relevant as it does limit the language and possibly techniques he can use

Comment: Just use loads of little images with a image for each state and damaged state :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using physics engine such as Box2D/Chipmunk to make a wall of boxes like in games such as Angry Bird?